# Debugging a Scheme program

Tags: scheme, text-to-speech, festival

I am using [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/), a text-to-speech synthesizer, for a project.  It has a Scheme scripting language.  I'm very new to scheme and hope someone can help.  I just want to see the current configuration parameters of Festival.  I have a Scheme prompt and can change existing parameters with the following commands:

```
festival> (Parameter.set 'Horse 3)
3
festival> (Parameter.get 'Horse)
3
```

Now, I'd like to see every parameter at once, instead of just one at a time.  Is there a simple Scheme command to do this?

Comment: It seems like Parameters in this case are specific to Festival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how Parameter is internally represented. If it is an association list, you can just print it. You can also try these free Scheme debuggers:

- [Schemeide](http://schemeide.sourceforge.)
- [Psd](http://www.cs.tut.fi/staff/pk/scheme/psd/article/article.html)